# Set status as "Focusing" in Microsoft Teams [HOW]; MyAnalytics focus time sets status as "Busy"

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office, outlook-addin, microsoft-teams

I am trying to set my status as "**Focusing**" in **Microsoft Teams**.

Using the MyAnalytics, I was able to schedule focus time on my calendar and I was hoping to see my status as "Focusing" during that time.
But my status changes to "Busy" (not "DND"/ not "Focusing") during the scheduled time.

Am I missing something or is the some other way to set "Focusing" as my status.